# When I update an app, it makes me put in my password then in says update again. It never updated, why does it do that?

Tags: ipad

The app never updates and it keeps telling me to put in my password.

Comment: Did you change your appleid at some point?  Did you buy or receive a phone from someone else that already had apps downloaded under the sellers appleid, but then you switched to your own?  What you are describing sounds like apps that want to update under a different appleid.

Comment: Try from another connection - a friend's house, starbucks, etc. If no joy, in iTunes - sync; backup; restore. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

Save your app settings, then try reinstalling it from the ground up.
Looks like an account misconfigure.